# WebdriverIO - .waitForExist is not a function

Tags: webdriver-io

I am using WebDriverIO - Javascript for automation.  Page object model is used.
When I run the script I get below exception

**.waitForExist is not a function**

Comment: Could you please provide some code for this?

Answer (score 0):

try like this [details](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForExist/)

```
$(selector).waitForExist({ timeout, reverse, timeoutMsg, interval })
```

Comment: await browser.url("https://.......")

      await browser.setTimeout({ 'script': 60000 })
      
      await browser.setTimeout({ 'pageLoad': 60000, 'implicit': 5000 })

//      await browser.pause(20000)
      await browser.$("#input-search").click()
      await browser.$("#input-search").setValue("8000")

Comment: Chrome browser is opened and URL is loaded.  It is not able to identify any of the operation methods like click, setValue etc..

Comment: I deleted node-Modules folder and reinstalled all packages.  It is working